# Did I just ruined my rear shock? fox float :(

Tags: maintenance, replacement, shocks

My shock was quite ok, but I still tried to service it.

After dissembling, it has absolutely no oil in it. I filled with 5 ml of fox fluid, put everything together. After installed to the frame started to pump some air slowly.

The problem is that if the sag is correct, than a 20 cm drop can make the shock travel 90% (150psi 73kg), now it's 210psi, and the sag is smaller then 10%, but from an average 30cm drop still travels 70-80%.

Has anyone some idea what could I possibly messed up to have this result?

Comment: Is it possible, that because the shock was nearly dry, and I also lubricate the joint points on the frame, the travel increased, and I did not make any mistake... ? After a night there is no oil leak.

Comment: Are there any adjustments on rear shock (rebound, dampening, lockout) you could accidentally 'messed up' while servicing it?

Comment: Did the documentation for your paticular shock explain the oil was needed? If so, did you also put the correct weight oil in?

Comment: Well this is the oficial page for my shock: https://www.ridefox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/07/eng/rear_shocks/float_rp2.htm#Setting_Sag It does not say that I have to put oil to it, because it says to let the service do it... All of the YT videos used the same fox fluid which is 7WT. These is no such a thing that a shock does not need lubrication. I made this, because it started to make some rubbery noise when i compressed it.

Answer (score 3):

Really it could be anything, from oil weight to actually damaging something in the shock, to merely a seal issue (allowing easier internal air movement).

If you did not change the seals but it was dry when you opened it up and you opened it because you heard rubbery noises when you compressed it, then i'd be putting my money on it needing some internal seals changed.

Alternatively your shock might be totally FINE! You might have just messed up your shock pump gauge and be seeing the wrong pressure. Borrow another shock pump/guage etc to check.

The good news is you probably haven't ruined it, in the sense you need another shock, but I wouldn't go riding it until you figure out what's wrong.

The bad news is that we can't REALLY help you without actually having you photograph the shock as you take it apart and put it together again, in extreme detail.

It's unlikely that nothing went wrong (unless it's just your gauge showing the wrong pressure all of a sudden); you would still get similar travel from the unlubed shock, it just wouldn't be as smooth.